# Calculating inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: objective-c

I want to find out Sin⁻¹ values. For that purpose initially  i am converting radians into degrees using macro `

```
#define DEGREES(radians) (radians * 180 / M_PI)
```

And then after using asin() function to find out sin inverse values as below `

```
double trig;

 trig = [currentVal doubleValue];
  display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g" ,asin(DEGREES(trig)) ];
```

It is displaying double value Because of using format specifier as double value. But i want to display in degrees????? Any one could help me plz

Comment: What do you mean, display in degrees? How do you want the output to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g º" ,asin(DEGREES(trig)) ];
```

Will show as xº if `asin(DEGREES(trig)) = x`

Answer (score 7):

It should be the other way around: `DEGREES(asin(trig))`

`asin(x)` *returns* radians; it's this value that you need to convert to degrees, not the *parameter* `x` of the `asin(x)`.